# no bootable devices | Win8 UEFI + Ubuntu | after boot-repair "winEFI detected, do you ..."

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I have a Dell Precision M6700 with Win8 preinstalled. Wanted to install Ubuntu. I am not an expert on grub/boot/UEFI stuff, so followed advice on different forums.

Did the following:

1. unchecked "Turn on fast startup" option in Win8
2. turned off secure boot
3. created free space for Ubuntu in Win8 Disk Management (it had 3 primary partitions: recovery, efi, C with Win8 installed on it)
4. installed ubuntu from a pen-drive using "something else" option. (swap, / , /HOME). As advised I pointed to "/dev/sdb" for installing.
5. after restarting I still could run only Win8.
6. I entered ubutu live (pen-drive) and used Boot-Repair. It found a "WinEFI detected, do you want to backup and rename the files?" problem.
   I (stupidly) clicked yes.
7. Now I can't boot anything. There is only "No bootable device -- strike F1 to retry boot ...". Tried to undo the thing using again ubuntu live (pen-drive), chose the 
   "Restore EFI backups" option of Boot-Repair, but did not help at all.

Could you please advise? I'm getting a bit anxious.

---

// added: the Boot-Info report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6798994

Comment: Dell's do not usually have the 'buggy' UEFI that the Boot-REpair rename is a work around for. But the undo you did should let you boot from Windows again. Post the link to the Create BootInfo report. Is part of Boot-Repair: Different Dell, but may have useful info:  http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2013/11/14/ubuntu-on-the-precision-m3800.aspx

Comment: The Boot-Info report:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6798994/

Comment: I didn't understand why you pointed to `/dev/sdb`. Does the computer have two drive, `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`? Or is the pen-drive `/dev/sdb`?

Comment: I am not sure about it all now. As far as I can remember, at the time of installing Ubuntu it is was all /dev/sdb1, /dev/sdb2, ... etc, so naturally it would be /dev/sdb. I don't think I could be as careless as to confuse it with the pen-drive, but then I am not 100% sure now. In the Boot-Info report it's all /dev/sdaX.

Comment: And now in the Boot-Info report pen-drive is designated by /dev/sdb.

Comment: What seems logical to me now is using Boot-Repair's "Reinstall GRUB" option. In "GRUB location" tab: OS to boot by default: sda7 (Ubuntu 13.10) and "Separate /boot/efi partition" set to sda3. Should that create a boot loader for /dev/sda and work? I don't want to mess things any further ...

Comment: This sounds reasonable. But I don't know for sure. Best backup any valuable data (by booting from pen-drive) before going any farther.

Comment: With UEFI you still specify to install the boot loader to sda and it installs to the efi partition. You do not look like you have all the Windows boot files in the efi partition and Boot-Repair would not have deleted them. You may also need repairs from a Windows repair flash drive. Do not install grub to a partition with either BIOS or UEFI.

Comment: Oldfred, I did use the Windows repair drive (automatic repair). Now it boots Windows. When trying to boot Ubuntu (from a F12-forced boot menu) info about wrong partition table pops up. Will fight with it tomorrow. For the time being at least Windows is again available. Thank you, guys, a lot for help!

Comment: Hey I'm facing the same issue, followed the same steps as you. Could you please post how did you solve it? Thanks!